# CROSS JOIN in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have DB2 and I have the following Query

```
SELECT t1.MyName, t2.MySalary
FROM Employee t1 CROSS JOIN Salary t2
```

I got the following Exception :

> An unexpected token "CROSS" was found following "me  FROM "Employee"
>   t1  ".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104,
>   SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: Your error does not match the query.  There is no `me FROM "Employee" t1 ` in the query in the question.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, a cross join is the Cartesian product of the two tables.

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.MyName, t2.MySalary
FROM Employee t1, Salary t2
```

Comment: I need to use CROSS JOIN  ?

Comment: @Margo Stefin: No, you don't.  Try the query.

Comment: I need to use CROSS JOIN it self

Comment: @Margo Stefin: Ok. Explain to me exactly what you think a CROSS JOIN is.  I'm telling you my query in the answer is a cross join, without using the words CROSS JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.MyName, t2.MySalary
FROM Employee t1 Join Salary t2 on 1=1
```

The ON clause includes a condition that is always true to force the Cartesian join to occur.